# Use write-region in read-only buffer

Tags: interactive, read-only-mode

I am writing a custom function which is supposed to write selected text to some arbitrary file on the system. It does something like

```
(defun write-region-to-file (&optional arg)
  (interactive "*p")
  (write-region (point) (mark-marker) "/path/to/file/other/then/visited"))
```

If I then run it in a read-only buffer I get

```
command-execute: Buffer is read-only: #<buffer ...>
```

Why is this happening? I don't do any modification to the visited one, I am writing to a completely different file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interactive code `*` is used to:  "*Signal an error if the current buffer is read-only. Special.*"

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html

Thus, the line that reads `(interactive "*p")` can be changed to eliminate the asterisk.

NOTE:  In the example, the optional argument `ARG` is not used.  Thus, consider changing `(&optional arg)` to just `()`; and, consider changing the interactive statement to just `(interactive)`.